# C++ Struct Error “No matching function for call 'erase'

Tags: c++

vector erase function brings up an error whereas clear function works.
What is the reason for this..?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct person_id{
    person_id() = default;
    person_id(int id) : p_id (id) {}

    bool operator==(const person_id& other) { return p_id == other.p_id; }
    int p_id;
};
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<person_id> people;

    person_id tmp_person;
    tmp_person.p_id = 5;
    people.push_back(tmp_person);

    people.erase(5); // error : “No matching function for call 'erase'
    people.clear(); // works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, try `people.erase(people.begin() + 0);` instead. You cannot provide a key in a `std::vector::erase` (like e.g. in a `std::set`). Only, iterators are accepted.

Comment: [`std::vector<T>::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector::erase()` takes as argument the `iterator`.
So if you want to delete the 6th element you need to do in this way:  `people.erase(people.begin() + 5);`. If you want to delete the 1st element just use `people.erase(people.begin());`

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Edit:
Erase element which will meet the conditions:

The 1st way:
Create temp `person_id` with needed id, and find it in the vector:

```
person_id personToCheck(5);
auto iter = std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), personToCheck);
if(iter != people.end())
{
   people.erase(iter);
}
```

The 2nd way:
Create new `operator==` in the `person_id` class:
`bool operator==(const int ID) { return p_id == ID; }`

```
auto iter = std::find(people.begin(), people.end(), 5); //the 5 is the ID
if(iter != people.end())
{
   people.erase(iter);
}
```

The 3rd way:
Create lambda and use it to find the element in the vector

```
auto iter = std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [](const person_id &p) { return p.p_id == 5; });
if(iter != people.end())
{
   people.erase(iter);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the `<vector>` `erase` function prototype:

```
iterator erase (iterator position);
```

You can't call it with an `int` parameter. You need a `vector::iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

[`vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) doesn't know that by number *5* you mean the person with ID=5. You need to tell it so by providing an iterator to that item.

First [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) the item you want to erase by searching for that condition.

```
auto itr = std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [](const person_id &p) { return p.p_id == 5; });
```

Then, if the search was successful, you can erase the iterator that was returned.

```
if (itr != people.end())
    people.erase(itr);
```